# Auto increment insert mysql

Tags: mysql

**Hello.**
I don't know much about MySQL. So I'm trying to explain my problem with pictures. Sorry.

do I add an entry to the user_id column you see in the image?

[image: Please see]

```
insert into balance_transaction (user_id) 
values('What should I add here.)
```

Comment: That shouldn't be an auto-increment column in this table. It should be a foreign key to the user table. You need to look up the ID of the appropriate user.

Comment: You put `1` if the user is `admin`, `2` if it's `hakkimtn`.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to insert the results of a query from the `user` table.

Comment: You mean when you add a user to the users table, you want to add a row to this table? Use `new.id`.

Comment: You need to explain what you're trying to do in the question, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use `new.id` to get the value of the auto-increment ID.

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_add_balance_trans
AFTER INSERT ON user
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO balance_transaction (user_id) VALUES (new.id);
```

Replace `id` with the actual name of the auto-increment column in the `user` table.

Comment: I want to ask one more thing. for example, VALUES (new.id) to select the 1-admin user; What should i write?

I want to send a message to every user who subscribes to the site. I need to define a user in the sender section. Can I define a 1-admin user?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Just use `user_id = 1` to mean the admin user.

Comment: Command to send this message
   
      INSERT INTO message (from_user_id, to_user_id, text)
   VALUES(user_id= 1,new.id,selam)
   
   Error.

Comment: `VALUES (1, new.id, "selam")`

Comment: Better to not hard-code an ID: `INSERT INTO message(from_user_id, to_user_id, text) SELECT users.id, new.id, "selam" FROM users WHERE users.name = "admin"`

Comment: ERROR :/ https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/11/19/RJvBV1.png  https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/11/19/RJvitA.png

Comment: I'm guessing the names of the columns in your `users` table. Of course you need to fix them to be the correct column names.

Comment: I did. Thank you very very very much. :)

Comment: Can we schedule the message code we generated above? The user has registered for the site. and the message was sent after 3 minutes.

Comment: You want it to wait 3 minutes, or it's taking 3 minutes when it should be immediate? If you want it to wait 3 minutes, you could put the registration time in the users table, and use the Event Scheduler to run a query every minute that sends a message to everyone registered 3 minutes earlier.

Comment: A difficult job :)

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to see in that image, it's not an error message. But this comment thread is inappropriate, this is not a tutoring service.